# How can I let Servlet to trigger javascript function after reading data from Mysql Database?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I am using servlet to print HTML tag to make it a HTML page. I have some data to be retrieved from Mysql database. After that I want to let my servlet to automatically trigger the destinated function by calling "function name(data)" (something like that). To pass the data retrieved and use it as parameter to the javascript to carry out some calucation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), just do

```
out.print("<script>functionName(" + dataInJsFormat + ");</script>");
```

Or better, since HTML is intented to be placed in [JSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)

```
request.setAttribute("dataInJsFormat", dataInJsFormat);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

with in `page.jsp`

```
<script>functionName(${dataInJsFormat});</script>
```

Comment: thank sir, since i am not going to use jsp. I think i will choose the first method. I have two question now actually
1) Can I call ("<script>functionName(" + dataInJsFormat + ");</script>"); inside <body>?

2) Is there any sample about what is happening inside  dataInJsFormat?? How to make my data into js format?

Comment: 1) Your choice. 2) Uh, just the same format as you use in plain vanilla JS.

Comment: For example, i want to make this chart
http://code.google.com/intl/zh-TW/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart.html

I want to make data.addRows([
          ['2004', 1000, 400],
          ['2005', 1170, 460],
          ['2006', 660, 1120],
          ['2007', 1030, 540]
        ]);

to be replaced by the data i have retrieved from db
is that i just make my data to something like this format and then pass as parameter?

Comment: For example , can I make string = ['data', data, data] (data is retrieved from db). And then calling out.print("<script>drawChart(" + string + ");</script>");

At the js side, I modify the code to be function drawChart(String) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addRows([String   
        ]);

Comment: Just use exactly that format then? In Servlet/JSP you're basically **generating** JS code, you're not **running** JS code in there.

Comment: Okay I got the point. I will have a try first, thanks so much for your help sir!

Comment: it seems that it is not working by simply calling out.print("<script>functionName(" + dataInJsFormat + ");</script>");

Comment: Apparently you're printing syntactically invalid JS code. Fix the syntax errors accordingly. You of course also need to make sure that the function has already been definied before you're printing that line, but that should be obvious enough. It would by the way be so much easier if you expirement on a plain vanilla HTML page first and once you get it to work, then let the servlet (or better, JSP), print exactly that HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Comet (Reverse Ajax)